# Identifying interest / topic from text

Tags: python, nltk, lda, gensim, nltk-trainer

I am attempting to build a model that will attempt to identify the interest category / topic of supplied text. For example:

> Shop for Bridal Wedding Sarees from our exhausting variety of beautiful and designer sarees. Get great deals, quality stitching and
>   Free International delivery.

would resolve to a top level category like:

> Fashion or Wedding Fashion

To acheive this, I have used Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) which is a topic model that generates topics based on word frequency from a set of documents.

So I got topics of document as below but don't find way to map them to human understandable format

> topic #0 (0.500): 0.100*sare + 0.060*intern + 0.060*get + 0.060*deal +
>   0.060*exhaust + 0.060*design + 0.060*free + 0.060*qualiti + 0.060*shop + 0.060*great
>
> topic #1 (0.500): 0.063*sare + 0.063*beauti + 0.063*deliveri +
>   0.063*stitch + 0.063*varieti + 0.063*wed + 0.062*bridal + 0.062*great + 0.062*shop + 0.062*qualiti

I have used this [script](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/79360_850b2a69980c4488b1db95987a24867a.html) to implement above things.

So the Question is How to map above identified topics to human readable category like Fashion?

Comment: Did you forget to ask your question?

Comment: @alexis Please check. edited my question.

Comment: Um, ok, so if you've done all this, what is keeping your from just extracting  the top-ranked keyword(s) from each result? What do you actually want to see as your "human readable category" for the two examples you give?

Comment: Given that neither "Fashion" nor "Wedding Fashion" is part of the text, I understand you are actually looking to categorize the text rather than extract a chunk that represents the text. I see this more of a classification problem rather than a topic modelling one.

Comment: @bogs You are right. I want to categorize given text. For example, Sports, Technology, Fashion, Food, Travel etc.. Would you suggest which classification algorithm help to resolve such problem in python / nltk?

Comment: @alexis I want to categorize the text. If there are talks about food in text, then i want to tag that text as Food. If there are talks about sports in text, then i want to tag that text as Sports. same way Travel, Technology etc..

Comment: You'll need to train a classification model on the output of you LDA model to predict the set of tags you are interested in.

Comment: There may be pre-built models out there, but if you want a specific set of tags then  you'll have to train yourself.

Comment: If you can figure out the set of "human readable" categories you want to see, you could train a classifier using the weighted terms as features. But you'd need a (substantial) training corpus that you've already annotated with the desired categories.

Comment: @aberger Can you tell me name of pre-built models?

Comment: @GBD I just said that there may be models out there, but I have no idea is there are or what they're called. They would also be trained on different data and would therefore not work as well for you as a model trained on your data!